# Don't understand why code till question 3 works fine but not working for question 4 and 5

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a simple FAQ page using HTML, CSS and JavaScript but don't understand why the first three event listeners work while the rest are not working.

**JavaScript:**

```
document.getElementById("question1").querySelector("span").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.querySelector(".answer1").classList.toggle("active-state");
});
document.getElementById("question2").querySelector("span").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.querySelector(".answer2").classList.toggle("active-state");
})
document.getElementById("question3").querySelector("span").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.querySelector(".answer3").classList.toggle("active-state");
})

document.getElementById("question4").querySelector("span").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.querySelector(".answer4").classList.toggle("active-state");
})
document.getElementById("question5").querySelector("span").addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.querySelector(".answer5").classList.toggle("active-state");
})
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>FAQ</h1>
      <p id="question1">How many team members can I invite?<span><img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt=""></span>
      </p>
      <p class="answer active-state answer1">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit
        on team members
        for the Premium plan.</p>
      <hr>
      <p id="question2"> What is the maximum file upload size?<span><img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg"
            alt=""></span></p>
      <p class="answer active-state answer2"> No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage
        space.</p>
      <hr>
      <p id="question3"> How do I reset my password?<span><img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt=""></span></p>
      <p class="answer active-state answer3"> Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from your
        profile page.
        A reset link will be emailed to you.</p>
      <hr>
      <p id="question4"> Can I cancel my subscription?<span><img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt=""></span></p>
      <p class="answer active-state answer4"> Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions asked.
      </p>
      <hr>
      <p id="question5"> Do you provide additional support?<span><img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt=""></span>
      </p>
      <p class="active-state answer answer5"> Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during
        normal business
        hours. </p>
```

```js
document.getElementById("question1").querySelector("span").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".answer1").classList.toggle("active-state");
});
document.getElementById("question2").querySelector("span").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".answer2").classList.toggle("active-state");
})
document.getElementById("question3").querySelector("span").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".answer3").classList.toggle("active-state");
})

document.getElementById("question4").querySelector("span").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".answer4").classList.toggle("active-state");
})
document.getElementById("question5").querySelector("span").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".answer5").classList.toggle("active-state");
})
```

```css
.active-state {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<h1>FAQ</h1>
<p id="question1">How many team members can I invite?<span><img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="1"></span>
</p>
<p class="answer active-state answer1">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.</p>
<hr>
<p id="question2"> What is the maximum file upload size?<span><img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg"
            alt="2"></span></p>
<p class="answer active-state answer2"> No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.
</p>
<hr>
<p id="question3"> How do I reset my password?<span><img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="3"></span></p>
<p class="answer active-state answer3"> Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from your profile page. A reset link will be emailed to you.</p>
<hr>
<p id="question4"> Can I cancel my subscription?<span><img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="4"></span></p>
<p class="answer active-state answer4"> Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions asked.
</p>
<hr>
<p id="question5"> Do you provide additional support?<span><img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="5"></span>
</p>
<p class="active-state answer answer5"> Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business hours. </p>
```

Comment: Working fine for me, try executable snippet.

Comment: I tried with the code detailed in your question and it works as expected.  Please make sure that your question contains enough information to reproduce the issue.  Sorry about the edit, I thought I was typing into the answer box but was actually editing the question.

Comment: Works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this does work as expected, **and I know this isn't part of the question**, but there is a better way to do this. I didn't want to let a teaching moment pass by. What if you have 100 or 200 questions... that's going to end up being a lot of JS based on your ID structure.

For your questions, change out your `<p id="question...">` for `<p class="question">`

Remove the `answer1`, `answer2`, `answer3`, etc. from your answer classes.

**Then collect all the questions:**

```
let questions = document.querySelectorAll(".question span");
```

**Then collect all the answers:**

```
let answers = document.querySelectorAll(".answer");
```

...and loop through them like this...

```
for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  questions[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    answers[i].classList.toggle("active-state");
  });
}
```

This basically says, "For each question span I click on, toggle the `active-state` class for each of the answers."

Then you can have as many questions as you would like and you don't have to worry about adding more JS.

View this snippet to see how it works:

```js
let questions = document.querySelectorAll(".question span");
let answers = document.querySelectorAll(".answer");

for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
  questions[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    answers[i].classList.toggle("active-state");
  });
}
```

```css
.active-state {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<h1>FAQ</h1>
<p class="question">How many team members can I invite?
  <span><img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="1"></span>
</p>
<p class="answer active-state">You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is no limit on team members for the Premium plan.</p>
<hr>
<p class="question"> What is the maximum file upload size?<span><img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg"
            alt="2"></span></p>
<p class="answer active-state"> No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted storage space.
</p>
<hr>
<p class="question"> How do I reset my password?<span><img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="3"></span></p>
<p class="answer active-state"> Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password” from your profile page. A reset link will be emailed to you.</p>
<hr>
<p class="question"> Can I cancel my subscription?<span><img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="4"></span></p>
<p class="answer active-state"> Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions asked.
</p>
<hr>
<p class="question"> Do you provide additional support?<span><img src="./images/icon-arrow-down.svg" alt="5"></span>
</p>
<p class="active-state answer"> Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open during normal business hours. </p>
```

Comment: Thanks, man. While the code itself was working but due to some CSS issue, it was not reflecting. I'm new to using JavaScript on the front end even though I know some Js but still, I don't understand how to apply all those on DOM.

Comment: Glad to help out.